# FailedPreconditionError (see above for traceback): GetNext() failed because the iterator has not been initialized

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I built a Dataset pipeline for input data when making predictions.However,when I tried the code,an error occurred

> FailedPreconditionError (see above for traceback): GetNext() failed because the iterator has not been initialized. Ensure that you have run the initializer operation for this iterator before getting the next element.
>            [[Node: IteratorGetNext_259 = IteratorGetNextoutput_shapes=[[?,227,227,6]], output_types=[DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]]

the iterator to traverse the dataset was defined as following:

```
for k in range(num_init_ops):
with tf.device('/cpu:0'):


    pre_data.append(PreDataGenerator(pre_file,
                                mode='predicting',
                                batch_size=batch_size,
                                num_classes=num_classes,
                                shuffle=False,
                                iterator_size=iterator_size,
                                kth_init_op=k))

    # create an reinitializable iterator given the dataset structure
    iterator = Iterator.from_structure(pre_data[k].data.output_types,
                                       pre_data[k].data.output_shapes)
    next_batch = iterator.get_next()

# Ops for initializing the two different iterators
predicting_init_op.append(iterator.make_initializer(pre_data[k].data))
```

the *for* cycle was written because I expect to create multiple dataset init-ops for splitting data into different iterators so as to prevent accumulating memory calls causing OOM errors(I wonder if doing this will work).

I am certain that the iterator is initialized(it outputs correct structure when debugging). Here is my Tensorflow session code:

```
with tf.Session(config=config) as sess:
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
# sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())
saver.restore(sess, './checkpoints_grade1/model_epoch46.ckpt')  # todo:

print("{} Start predicting...".format(datetime.now()))

for j in range(num_init_ops+1):#todo:

    print('{} Initializing {} iterator'.format(datetime.now(),j))

    # Initialize iterator with the predicting dataset
    sess.run(predicting_init_op[j])

    for i in range(iterator_size):

        # get next batch of data
        img_batch = sess.run(next_batch)#todo:?

        # And run the predicting op
        img_batch = tf.reshape(img_batch, (1, 227, 227, 6))
        pred = sess.run(softmax, feed_dict={x: sess.run(img_batch)})
        predicted_label = pred.argmax(axis=1)
        predictions.append(predicted_label[0])
        output_file.write(str(i) + ' , ' + str(predicted_label[0]) + '\n')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I control the prediction program through [a shell script](https://github.com/ChengYeung1222/finetune_alexnet_v2/blob/master/for_cycle_2.sh), each time I start predicting a batch of samples so that the memory just doesn't run out. The problem solved.

```
#!/bin/bash 
for ((i=0;i<9;i++))
do
    python classifier_v4.py --iter_epoch $i
done
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize iterator:

```
sess.run(iterator.initializer)
```

And do training like this:

```py
next_batch = iterator.get_next()
sess.run(iterator.initializer)

for epoch in range(n_epochs):
    while True:
        try:
            batch = sess.run(next_batch)
            # feed data, train
            # ...
        except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
            sess.run(iterator.initializer)
            break
```

Alternatively, while defining your `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices` instance you can specify how many epochs to train:

```py
data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices({
            'x':train_data,
            'y':train_labels
            }).repeat(n_epochs).batch(batch_size)
iterator = data.make_initializable_iterator()
```

With this you don't need the `for epoch in range(n_epochs)` loop:

```py
next_batch = iterator.get_next()
sess.run(iterator.initializer)

while True:
    try:
        batch = sess.run(next_batch)
        # feed data, train
        # ...
    except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
        break
```

Comment: I changed the code as suggested, still the problem left. And when I put the cursor on the _next_batch_ variable, it shows that **name 'next_batch' can be not defined less... (Ctrl+F1)  Inspection info: This inspection warns about local variables referenced before assignment.**

Comment: Cannot tell without seeing your code. Upload it somewhere and post here a link. I'll take a look.

Comment: I just uploaded the repository on github.This link is about the prediction script.[https://github.com/ChengYeung1222/finetune_alexnet_v2/blob/master/classifier_v3.py]   Thank you for your precious time!!

Comment: [link](https://github.com/ChengYeung1222/finetune_alexnet_v2/blob/master/classifier_v3.py)